# Commit a folder in Subversion

Tags: svn

How do you commit an entire folder? Isn't it just...?

```
svn ci --username USERNAME folder-name
```

Update a svn repository. I do not want to upload file by file. I just want the command, I do not need a tutorial or a lecture. Thanks!

Comment: "Isn't it just...?" - what happens when you try? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It says...
svn: E155007: 'folder-name' is not a working copy.

Comment: This is unexpected. Did you `svn checkout` a working copy before? Please [edit] your question and provide some more information on context and what you're trying to achieve. As it stands, it's hard to reproduce your problem. More information can be found on [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `add` the folder (or any new files within it) before you can `commit` them. You can do the following:

```
svn add folder-name
svn commit
```